# Ubuntu 15.10 64bit Desktop invalid Checksums

Tags: system-installation, 15.10, md5sum

Is the MD5 checksum for [Ubuntu 15.10](http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.10/) incorrect or is there an issue for me?

I'm getting a value of **3f29c5423393fc282216ed80e25af7c5** whereas the website is reporting an expected value of **ece816e12f97018fa3d4974b5fd27337**. (Listed here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/15.10/MD5SUMS).

I tried downloading the file again but got the same MD5. I also checked the SHA1SUM and that was incorrect too.

I originally checked as after burning the ISO I couldn't run the installer properly.

I tried checking the 14.04 MD5 values and they were correct for me.

Comment: I get ece816e12f97018fa3d4974b5fd27337. The file is 1178386432 bytes, and I downloaded it sometime ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the checksums don't match, then you have a corrupted file. I've downloaded and checked it now and everything is OK for me. You should download it again via BitTorrent (recommended).

Comment: Yes, the torrent version had the correct md5 hash. The file sizes of the two are identical and I downloaded it twice and got the same incorrect hash which is weird... Thanks for looking at this